# Behavior of scanf() in C++

Tags: c++

What is happening when I enter a string, when scanf() expect float?
I thought it would be some  exception, but I got infinite loop. Why, and how I can control this?

Okay, code is here

```
int main(){
    float f;
    scanf("%f", &f);
    cout << "f = " << f << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right...can you show some code please and thanks

Comment: Read the data in as a string, and then check the input to make sure it is numerical before trying to parse it as a float. C++ does not do input sanity checking for you.

Comment: The function `scanf` works EXACTLY the same way in C++ as it does in C. Which is also largely what `cin >> floatvar` wil do. This means it will read "all that it can eat", but if it encounters something that is "not what it expected", it will stop reading and leave whatever is unsuitable in the buffer.

Comment: @MatsPetersson except that `scanf` has a useful return value and `operator>>` isn't allowed to :)

Comment: `I thought it would be some exception,`  If the function hasn't documented that it throws an exception, don't expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: @hobbs: No operator >> in itself just returns the stream, but translate the stream to a boolean and you get a useful value to check from streams too (ok, it may not tell you WHAT or HOW much you read, but nearly always that information is pretty much useless anyway, because you have no way to retry without knowing EXACTLY what you need to change)

Comment: Further to PaulMcKenzie's comment: Standard C functions CAN NOT throw exceptions. C++ functions (such as `cin >> f;` have the possibility to throw exceptions) - in fact `cin.exceptions(std::istream::failbit | std::istream::badbit)` or something similar would cause code to throw an exception if input is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` reads as much as it can, but it stops if it hits the end of the input or if the input doesn't match the specification. It returns the number of items it read, and if it stopped early then that number will be less than the number of specifiers in your format string, and any input that didn't match will still be in the input buffer for a future read.

e.g.:

If you `int count = scanf("%f", &val)` and the input is "1.23", then `val` will be `1.23`, `count` will be `1`, and the input will be consumed.

If you `int count = scanf("%f", &val)` and the input is "George", then `val` will be unchanged, `count` will be `0`, and "George" will still be waiting on stdin for another read to use.

You can detect a failure by comparing `count` to the number of things that you were trying to read, and if it's too low then recover somehow, or discard input and error.